# For faster indexed data access is it relevant to have higher cardinality in the first part of key?

Tags: indexing, hbase

Supposing that I am indexing a UUID string that combines various other UUIDs together :

- UUID1 : a highly repeated key ( defines a customer ID for example )
- UUID2 : a unique key that never repeats

Having the need to combine them both and index it together ( indexing using a sorted index mechanism ), is it better to combine it as:

a) UUID1 + UUID2

or

b) UUID2 + UUID1

The usecase above is for an HBase implemenation of the row's key design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The combination depends on search that you are going to do. Another considerations might be meaningless. You actually need only unique part of identifier, that is good enough and the best solution as you have more compact key. Try only not to use monotonously increasing values for the keys. Use byte arrays instead of string data type especially for key's.

Answer (score 1):

you might also want to think about hot spotting and region splitting.

the region splitting is done by the key. so if you will have a lot of operation on the same prefix (UUID1) you might get hot spotting.